# How can I show or not event time by condition in Fullcalendar.io?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using [Fullcalendar.io](http://fullcalendar.io/) for making some scheduler. 
I know that I can hide event time by displayEventTime attribute to false.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ 
  timeFormat: 'h:mm',
  displayEventTime: false,
});
```

but when I want to show some event's time in some condition, how can I do this?
I tried like this but it does not work.

```
//ev is the event object made by ajax call
if ( /*this event is confirmed*/ ) {
  ev.displayEventTime = true;
}
```